Is it possible to run multiple solana-test-validators on the same host?
I want to study the leadership schedule switch between multiple nodes in a local cluster of test validators. Is this even possible? Solana noob - pardon my ignorance.
tried running two instances - the second instance does not even start up - if i use a different ledger folder and port - they run distinct ledgers - there is no attempt at sync.

solana-test-validator does not perform any voting, so it isn't suited for a cluster. You'll need to setup full validators if you want to run a cluster.
The net scripts at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/net are designed to do exactly that. If you have a gcloud account, it's pretty easy to get started, you can do:
./gce.sh create -n 5 -c 1     #<-- Create a GCE testnet with 5 additional nodes (beyond the bootstrap node) and 1 client (billing starts here)
./net.sh start                #<-- Deploy the network from the local workspace and start processes on all nodes including bench-tps on the client node
./net.sh stop                 #<-- Stop running processes on all nodes
./gce.sh delete

But be careful, since they are full validators, the machines can be very expensive to run on cloud hardware!
